# Google Custom Search API use which timezone for counting the daily quota?

Tags: google-custom-search

Google Custom Search API has a free quota for 100 queries per day, so what timezone is used by the API for counting the daily quota?

GMT or my server setting or other?

Answer (score 1):

It used Pacific time to reset api key quota https://time.is/PT

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your quota page, https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/customsearch.googleapis.com/quotas and it says "Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT)."

Even if you are in Europe or use a language that is not US English, Google's daily quota still uses Pacific Time.

However, I wonder if it is really reset at 00:00 PT. I think it's been 24 hours since I used up the daily quota of a project, the usage now is still 100%. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Google Custom Search API has a free quota for 100 queries per day, so what timezone is used by the API for counting the daily quota?

answer is GMT

Comment: Any reference / url for it?

Comment: Custom Search JSON API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the API Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day.

If you need more than 10k queries per day and your Custom Search Engine searches 10 sites or fewer, you may be interested in the Custom Search Site Restricted JSON API, which does not have a daily query limit.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing    This have more details about billing.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see where to mention that the timezone used is GMT from your provided URL? How can you come up with this answer?